# Using a switch inside of a function

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n){
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("banner").style;
    if (n > 4) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = 4}

    switch (n) {
        case '1': x.backgroundImage = "url('1.jpg')";
            break;
        case '2': x.backgroundImage = "url('2.png')";
            break;
        case '3': x.backgroundImage = "url('3.jpeg')";
            break;
        case '4': x.backgroundImage = "url('4.png')";
            break;
    }

  }
```

This is my script.
What I want it to do, is when I press a button, it adds 1 or takes away 1 from the slideIndex, and depending on which slide index it's currently at I want to use the switch and then set the background image of the class "banner" to the image corresponding to the number. This doesn't seem to work however. What is wrong with it?

Comment: You might get rid of the **switch** altogether and just use **x.backgroundImage = "url('" + n + ".jpg')";**

Comment: @JonSG OP has a few .png in there as well

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("banner")` return node array, you should do like this : `document.getElementsByClassName("banner")[0]`;

Comment: `switch (slideIndex)` instead of _n_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because `n` is a number but your switch cases are strings. Just remove the quotes around your cases.

```
function showDivs(n){
    // ...

    switch (n) {
        case 1: // ...
        case 2: // ...
        case 3: // ...
        case 4: // ...
    }
}
```

Since your image names correspond to the value of `n`, another improvement you can make is to use `n` directly instead of going through the `switch`:

```
function showDivs(n){

    // ...

    var extension = n % 2 === 0 ? '.jpg' : '.png';
    x.backgroundImage = "url('" + n + extension +"')";
}
```

*Note*: You have two JPEG images with different extensions, you might consider renaming them to a consistent extension to simplify your use case. Otherwise you might want to stick to the `switch` statement.

---

As mentioned by **CoderGLM** in the comments, `document.getElementsByClassName("banner")` will return a node list of all elements with the class `banner`. This means you need to extract a certain element, probably the first one:

```
x = document.getElementsByClassName("banner")[0].style;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be affecting the background image of the class, did I do something wrong with the variable set up?

Comment: I forgot to adjust for the different extensions, edited now

Comment: You could also have an array of filenames and index into the array. That'd be more concise than a `switch`, but still fully flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("banner").style;
```

`x` is an array of elements with the class 'banner'. You should use id instead (`document.getElementById()`), however if you can ensure that there is only one element with the class 'banner' then just grab the 0th element.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("banner")[0].style;
```

---

A better solution might be

```
let slideIndex = 1;

const plusDivs = (n) => {
    slideIndex += n;
    showDivs(slideIndex);
};

const showDivs = (n) => {
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName('banner')[0].style;

    slideIndex = Math.min(4, Math.max(1, n)); // Clamp n between [1,4]

    const images = ['1.jpg', '2.png', '3.jpeg', '4.png'];
    x.backgroundImage = `url('${images[n]}')`;
};
```